# How to write rewrite .htaccess rule to allow new folder access?

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

The current cakephp .htaccess rules reroute all incoming requests to the app/webroot folder. See following rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

At the moment I still developing and I have created a "site" folder in the cakephp root folder. But when I try to access the folder from the browser I get redirected to due the cakephp rewrite. I've done some research but I can't seem to figure out the required regular expression to change the rule. How do I modify/append the .htaccess folder to allow access to the 'site' folder.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to modifying the .htaccess rules is to move your `site` folder to `app/webroot/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/cake_root/site
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/cake_root/site
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Regards

Comment: Almost right. Only this rule is needed though: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/+path/to/cake_root/site [NC]
RewriteRule ^ app/webroot%{REQUEST_URI} [L]`