# cake php htaccess not working(cake2)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, redirect

I have cake php app on the root and a folder on the root in this i have placed placed `index.html` . so my dir is

```
root
   ---app
   ---lib
   ---plugins
   ---vendors
   ---myfolder
```

so app url is `www.example.com` . and the folder url should `www.example.com/myfolder` .

my taccess on root is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**but when i hit url `www.example.com/myfolder` it is showing me error 404** . i also changed the htaccess like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/myfolder/(.*)$ http://example.com/myfolder/$1
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Update**
i also refer this one [how to redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538181/how-to-write-rewrite-htaccess-rule-to-allow-new-folder-access)
but notworking. any help will appriciated

Comment: What is the purpose of `myfolder`?

Comment: there is other web content

Comment: i also check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538181/how-to-write-rewrite-htaccess-rule-to-allow-new-folder-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add condition in `.htaccess` file to check if url not contains any world then don't apply the rule try to change your `.htaccess` file like this:-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !myfolder
 RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !myfolder
 RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]  
</IfModule>
```

hope this will helpfull.